# CSS Background URL

Tags: css, url, hyperlink, path, relative-path

Can someone help explain how exactly the CSS URL for a background image works? How exactly does the CSS know where to start looking up the URL? for example I have these 3 URLs

```
#web_content{ background: URL(images/background.jpg); }
#web_content{ background: URL(/images/background.jpg); }
#web_content{ background: URL(localhost:1234/newWebSite/images/background.jpg); }
```

I tried all 3 of these on different PCs. Using the same web browser that are the same versions and everything. Basically all that was different was the PC it ran on. Using the 1st example it showed only on one PC, the 2nd example showed on 2 PCs and the 3rd one showed on all of them... but of course in real life using that as the URL won't work. Can someone explain in detail how the URL finds the file?

Comment: the first two are related to the URL of the page, which you haven't told us -- is it also on `localhost:1234` or are you accessing it via a `file` URL or something else? Was it the same URL across all three PCs?

Comment: Not clear that if you tested on each PC locally, or each PC accessing some host.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first one says to look for a `image` folder in the same directory in which the CSS file is located and then point out the `background.jpg` file.

The second one says to go into the `root` folder then look for an `image` folder and then look for a file named `background.jpg`.

The third one says to go to a `domain` then look into `newWebSite` folder then in an `image` folder then point out the file `background.jpg`.

It totally depends on the structure of your directories that what URL to use and when. If your `CSS` and `Image` folders are in the same directory then you may write the URL like this:

```
background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
```

The `../` here will tell CSS file to go back one directory and then go into the `image` folder.

If your `image` folder is a subdirectory of the `css` folder then you may write like this:

```
background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
```

If you want to include a file from another website then you may write like this:

```
background-image: url(http://www.example.com/background.jpg);
```

If you want to locate a folder that is in your root directory of your website then you may write like this:

```
background-image: url(/images/background.jpg);
```

The `/` at the first here indicates the URL to go into the very first parent directory and then look for an `image` folder.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: just curious and slightly off topic but is this also the case for all the URLs used in web developing? things like javascript src URL and CSS links?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us enough information to give a direct answer to the question, so the best way I can think of to answer is to show you how to find the solution for yourself.

In any modern web browser, you can press F12 to bring up the dev tools window. Load the page with this window open.

Depending on which browser you're using, the exact dev tools features will differ, but they all provide the ability to see the network traffic that is happening within the browser. This will be on a tab page within the dev tools.

Find that network traffic tab, and you will see an entry for your page being loaded, along with entries for all the CSS, JS, images, and other resources.

This will show you the exact URL that the browser attempted to load. It will also show you any errors that occurred (eg a 404 Not found error).

Using this, you should be able to work out where the browser is looking for the files in each of the instances you described, and it should be fairly obvious from there how they differ and why it is working in some cases and not others.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This was actually a nice answer, if he had been more clear and said, look for an error in the console and correct your URI. That's what I do but we just should know the pattern of writing URLs.