# which is best way to set background url in css?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am new to mvc application and creating site in aspx view engine.
i have a css file in mycss/style.css and images are in images/img1.jpg.
    what is the difference between

```
 background: url("../images/img1.jpg") no-repeat;
 and background: url("~/images/img1.jpg") no-repeat;
```

in style.css

Comment: I don't think `~/` will work in css files.

Comment: what is difference in Dot (./Images) and double dot (../Images) in file path ?

Comment: `../Images` means go up one directory, then down to the `Images` folder. `./Images` means go to the `Images` folder in the current directory.

Comment: Are you saying that both ways work for you?

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809007/css-background-url) explains how exactly the css url works for background


  [1]:

Comment: As shown in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563235/where-does-asp-net-virtual-path-to-resolving-the-tilde) the `~` is handled in `System.Web.Mvc.dll`

Comment: The quotes, by the way, are optional.`background:url(../images/img1.jpg) no-repeat` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3):

```
background: url("../images/img1.jpg") no-repeat;
```

The above is relative to the current location. It goes up one folder, then down to the images folder and finally gets the picture file.

```
background: url("~/images/img1.jpg") no-repeat;
```

The above is invalid. The tilde means start at the site root. But CSS doesn't support that syntax. The equivalent would be `background: url("/images/img1.jpg") no-repeat;`.

Depending on your site layout, both will work. I tend to use root relative paths because if you move your CSS file to a different folder it might break with a path relative to the current location.

For a good discussion of relative vs site relative vs absolute, [see this article](http://jeffreybarke.net/2013/06/paths-and-urls-relative-and-absolute/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it this way `background: url("images/img1.jpg") no-repeat;`
without any 'prefix' which means 'the images in the **images** folder.

Comment: This is assuming that the images folder is in the same folder as the CSS. Which is probably not the case judging by the posted code in the question.

Answer (score -1):

This would be the correct way.

```
background: url("../images/img1.jpg") no-repeat;
```

Comment: How about explaining why the version with `~` wouldn't be correct as well?